# CSS Image caption text with float

Tags: html, css

Im having a CSS problem. I want the paragraph under the image to be an image caption. So it should be under the image. Am i explaining it correctly? What am i doing wrong? (You can copy the code down here and just watch it in a browser)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Page</title>

        <style type="text/css">

        .CaptionRight
    {
        float: right;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-left: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        display:block;
        border: 1px red solid;
    }

    .CaptionRight p
    {

        }

    body
    {
        width: 500px;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <p><span class="CaptionRight" style="width:300px;"><img src="http://www.dn.se/ImageHandler.axd/?id=1034780&imageFormat=original" alt="" />
        <p>
        -This should be the image caption right under the image.   
        </p></span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nunc lobortis at lacus in auctor. Phasellus urna ligula,
 accumsan ut nisl pharetra, porta egestas ligula.
 Integer ultrices dolor neque, dapibus cursus lorem
 volutpat sit amet. Aliquam volutpat tempus dapibus. 
Vestibulum blandit, quam sit amet lacinia laoreet, 
dui massa dictum turpis, sed mattis purus lorem non diam.
 Pellentesque imperdiet massa libero, et ultrices tellus tincidunt eu.
 Vivamus urna magna, congue nec imperdiet nec, eleifend vitae elit.
 Donec iaculis lorem elementum orci tempus rutrum.
 Donec vel tortor iaculis lacus lacinia tempus sed vel est. 
Suspendisse iaculis vestibulum tincidunt. Quisque varius 
sapien porttitor malesuada volutpat. Sed a sapien nisl.

        </p>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the P from the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Page</title>

        <style type="text/css">

        .CaptionRight
    {
        float: right;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-left: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        display:block;
        border: 1px red solid;
    }

    body
    {
        width: 500px;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <p><span class="CaptionRight" style="width:300px;"><img src="http://www.dn.se/ImageHandler.axd/?id=1034780&imageFormat=original" alt="" />This should be the image caption right under the image.</span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nunc lobortis at lacus in auctor. Phasellus urna ligula,
 accumsan ut nisl pharetra, porta egestas ligula.
 Integer ultrices dolor neque, dapibus cursus lorem
 volutpat sit amet. Aliquam volutpat tempus dapibus. 
Vestibulum blandit, quam sit amet lacinia laoreet, 
dui massa dictum turpis, sed mattis purus lorem non diam.
 Pellentesque imperdiet massa libero, et ultrices tellus tincidunt eu.
 Vivamus urna magna, congue nec imperdiet nec, eleifend vitae elit.
 Donec iaculis lorem elementum orci tempus rutrum.
 Donec vel tortor iaculis lacus lacinia tempus sed vel est. 
Suspendisse iaculis vestibulum tincidunt. Quisque varius 
sapien porttitor malesuada volutpat. Sed a sapien nisl.

        </p>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You got lucky Pogrindis

Comment: i dont understand! :{ You were faster than me!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have `<p></p>` tags inside another

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <style type="text/css">

 .CaptionRight{
    float: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    display:block;
    border: 1px red solid;
}


Body{
    width: 500px;
 }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<span class="CaptionRight" style="width:300px;"><img src="http://www.dn.se/ImageHandler.axd/?id=1034780&imageFormat=original" alt="" /><p>-This should be the image caption right under the image.</p></span>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc lobortis at lacus in auctor. Phasellus urna ligula, accumsan ut nisl pharetra, porta egestas ligula. Integer ultrices dolor neque, dapibus cursus lorem volutpat sit amet. Aliquam volutpat tempus dapibus. Vestibulum blandit, quam sit amet lacinia laoreet, dui massa dictum turpis, sed mattis purus lorem non diam. Pellentesque imperdiet massa libero, et ultrices tellus tincidunt eu. Vivamus urna magna, congue nec imperdiet nec, eleifend vitae elit. Donec iaculis lorem elementum orci tempus rutrum. Donec vel tortor iaculis lacus lacinia tempus sed vel est. Suspendisse iaculis vestibulum tincidunt. Quisque varius sapien porttitor malesuada volutpat. Sed a sapien nisl.
Etiam ultricies tincidunt sagittis. Cras tortor turpis, blandit eu tincidunt eu, malesuada sit amet nisl. In ullamcorper tellus est, et volutpat dui pretium id. Nullam a dolor orci. Vivamus volutpat nisl vel eros feugiat, sit amet elementum est eleifend. Phasellus lorem sem, adipiscing eu lacus consequat, hendrerit feugiat risus. Donec non adipiscing felis. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris tempus id magna at euismod. Quisque non justo eu nulla consequat feugiat sed vel diam. Nulla nec tortor rhoncus, tincidunt elit et, sagittis libero. Phasellus sed nibh et arcu elementum lacinia sit amet nec dolor. Phasellus dictum pulvinar erat vel auctor. Fusce nibh massa, molestie et elit fermentum, fringilla aliquam tellus. Donec pulvinar auctor risus, id auctor nisi pellentesque pellentesque.
Ut ut auctor metus. Curabitur sit amet dictum nunc. Aliquam dignissim erat ac nisl pellentesque, at pellentesque nisi auctor. Ut dapibus iaculis volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas hendrerit ipsum ut dolor commodo feugiat. Praesent eu purus eu ipsum pharetra commodo at at odio. Maecenas elementum urna vitae congue scelerisque. Donec vel laoreet lectus, ut laoreet odio. Nam ut accumsan quam, adipiscing tincidunt libero. Aenean quis felis libero.<br /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

...

<figure>
   <img src="#" alt="image">
   <figcaption>My caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nG2s/)

In this way?

Comment: That's HTML5, there's a `doctype` present.

Comment: The OP has not asked about a not HTML5 solution. And mine is the best way so far to do what he needs. A downvote should given for bad answers, not for the good ones.

Comment: The `doctype` shows its not HTML5, also you should mention it is a HTML5 solution.

Comment: We are in the 2013, wake up.

Comment: Fez, you cannot disregard the users who are not using HTML5 compatible brosers. Thats completely ignorant as there are numerous reasons why people need to stick with older browsers. Having a spat and saying "wake up" wont help you understand that.

Comment: Good reasons to stick on old browsers don't exist, exist bad reasons to not update web sites to run on new browsers.

Comment: Fez, you have a lot to learn, many companies cannot upgrade their browsers and are only permitted to use IE for example or a set version number of browsers, this is actually very common in the workplace.. I suspect this is news to you though. http://itexpertvoice.com/home/why-you-cant-pry-ie6-out-of-their-cold-dead-hands/

Its not the best thing in the world.. We all hate it but the fact remains. And you should be aware of it.

Comment: I work for banks and assurance companies, I know a bit about this world, but this is not a good reason to write old code. If the OP needs old code he **MUST** specify it.

Comment: :) Your answer works, there is not doubt, the first comment was merely an observation for which you could have updated your code.

Comment: In any case, sticking your piece of HTML in a document with the specified `doctype` is not valid HTML. And not writing valid HTML is never a good idea. That was my point originally. Especially since you didn't mention HTML5 in the answer. But that's all fixed now :)

Comment: We are here to help more people as possible with our answers, give an answer for a very specific case is most of the times useless.

Comment: This is browser statistics on my site for last 2 months: `40x IE 10.0, 29x IE 9.0, 40x IE 8.0, 20x IE 7.0, 25x IE 6.0, 5x IE?.? --> 191x Chrome, 163x Firefox, 159x IE, 42x Opera, 6x Safari, 1x Iron` People are still using old browsers.

Comment: If you need an answer for old browsers, specify it, that's all.

Comment: OP has specified it: `xhtml1-transitional.dtd`

Comment: no he has pasted a code with a doctype, without telling that he can't change it.

Comment: And you gave an answer, without telling that he should change it.

Comment: And he has also a `<title>Untitled Page</title>` which can be interpreted as an outdated IDE-generated code.

Comment: Good argument, it may be like you say. But because your answer is only for HTML5, it's good to provide full and correct answer. Well, now your answer is ok.